# CultureName of System assembly in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mono

While writing some code handling assemblies in C# I noticed inconsistencies in field values of `Assembly` object (example of `System` assembly):

```
> typeof(string).Assembly.FullName
"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

but when accessing `CultureName` field of `AssemblyName` object directly, its value is an empty string:

```
> typeof(string).Assembly.GetName().CultureName
""
```

When I run the same test on Linux (`mono 3.99`) I got another result:

```
> typeof(string).Assembly.GetName().CultureName
"neutral"
```

Why does .NET behaves that way? I couldn't find any information on msdn regarding default value of `CultureName` field in `AssemblyName` class or meaning of an
empty string. Does an empty string always refers to "neutral" culture name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CultureName` property was introduced in .Net 4.5 and the value of that property for an `Assembly` with the neutral culture must be equal to an empty string like the name of the invariant culture because the `CultureName` uses the`CultureInfo` property ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assemblyname.cs,95)):

```
public String CultureName
{
    get
    {
        return (_CultureInfo == null) ? null : _CultureInfo.Name;
    }
}
```

But in Mono the `CultureName` property has a different implementation ([source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/effa4c07ba850bedbe1ff54b2a5df281c058ebcb/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/AssemblyName.cs#L435)). Why different? I think developers of Mono know the answer.

```
public string CultureName { 
    get { 
        if (cultureinfo == null) 
            return null; 
        if (cultureinfo.LCID == CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.LCID) 
            return "neutral"; 
        return cultureinfo.Name; 
    } 
}
```

So if you want to check that an `AssemblyName` has the neutral culture, use the code below:

```
if (object.Equals(assemblyName.CultureInfo, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{ /* neutral culture */ }
```

Comment: Sources are always the best place to find answers, thank you! In fact, when you look deeper (into `CultureInfo`) code, there is a fragment where empty string is returned when locale name is `null`.